# Format JSON using regular expression

Tags: json, regex

I am trying to remove field and its value that is empty braces. Below JSON has contactList empty. So I want to remove that contactlist from the JSON.

I found some code here that can hide fields with null values using:

```
JsonString = JsonString.replaceAll('\"[^\"]*\":null','');
```

I tried to apply same logic by replacing null with empty braces but it doesn't work. `JsonString = JsonString.replaceAll('\"[^\"]*\":{}','');` and gives error:

> StringException: Invalid regex: Illegal repetition near index 7

Actual JSON Response: `[{"status":"Open","contactList":{}}]`
Desired: `[{"status":"Open"}]` assuming contactlist is empty.

Can someone suggest me how to correct my regular expression?

Comment: You should escape the {}

Comment: Hi Luc, So you suggest writing that as.. ` JsonString = JsonString.replaceAll('\"[^\"]*\":\{\}',''); `  ? I tried that but didnt work

Comment: Why are you processing JSON using regexp? Just manipulate the JS object, then turn it into a JSON string if you want using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thanks torazburo.. My application is in Java. I believe json.stringify will not work for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a regex like this:

```
/,?\"\w+\"\s*:\{\}/g
```

or

```
/\s*,?\s*\"[^\"]+\"\s*:\s*\{\s*\}\s*/g
```

To find and replace empty data.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/rK2aZ8/1)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response);
var keyToDelete = "contactList";

delete arr[keyToDelete];
```